# Is there an app for enabling "external to Salesforce" users to book ressources in Salesforce

Tags: servicecloud, calendar

I need an app or custom configuration to be able to book resources from an site outside of salesforce.
Resources in terms of events, like a tour of the city etc. Which will be recurring several times a  day, but will have limited space.
I need to display an calendar view to the users - and let them select a specific time - fill in their details and let the site send the information to Salesforce.

How could I accomplish the above?
Is there an app which can handle it, and how about letting external users access the booking system through a website?

I've looked at Booker25 - but it seems overkill for this simple booking system.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this will need a added layer of security like username/password as well and a bit of personalization as well,for instance the user should be able to track past attended events as well.I can help you out in this project. my email is piyushsinghal90@gmail.com

Comment: I will not use authorization.

Comment: I will not use authorization.
Thanks, but I'm currently not interested in consulting - Just want to know whether theres is an app handling this - or would I have to build it custom.